# require aid with a simple JavaScript HTML DOM function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to make a callback function,
after I leave an input form --> call a function to change bg color of text input..
and it doesnt work.

```
function makeBig() {

var y = document.getElementById("myText");
    y.value = y.value.toUpperCase();      

        function colorInput(y) {
        y.style.background = "yellow";

}
```

}`<input type="text" id="myText" onchange="makeBig()">`

Answer (score 1):

Your **makeBig()** function declares the function **colorInput(y)** but never calls it. Change:

```
 function colorInput(y) {
    y.style.background = "yellow";
 }
```

to

```
y.style.background = "yellow";
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function makeBig() {

var y = document.getElementById("myText");
    y.value = y.value.toUpperCase();      

                y.style.background = "yellow";

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" onchange="makeBig()">
```